# What is a good replacement for r6rs syntax-violation in racket?

Tags: racket

According to [DrRacket Docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=syntax-violation), the `syntax-violation` form is defined in `rnrs/syntax-case-6`. But I'd like to use the `syntax-case` from `racket/base` and avoid importing `rnrs/syntax-case-6` (and r6rs in general since it seems to have a different `syntax-case` implementation than the `racket/base`).

Is there another function from `racket/base` or `racket/racket` that can replace `syntax-violation`? Or, should I write my own version that raises an exception?

**--Edit--**

I tried to import `syntax-violation` from `racket/base`, but it seems to be missing from there:

```
racket 
Welcome to Racket v8.6 [cs].
> syntax-violation
syntax-violation: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition                             
  in module: top-level                                                            
 [,bt for context]                                                                
> (require racket/base)
> syntax-violation
syntax-violation: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition                             
  in module: top-level                                                            
 [,bt for context]                                                                
> (syntax-violation #f "error message" #f)
syntax-violation: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition                             
  in module: top-level                                                            
 [,bt for context]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [`raise-syntax-error`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._raise-syntax-error%29%29) in macro error handling, which raises an exception of type [`exn:fail:syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._exn%7E3afail%7E3asyntax%29%29). From the docs:

> Macros use this procedure to report syntax errors.

Example:

```lisp
(define-syntax (example stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((_) (raise-syntax-error 'example "no arguments" stx))
    ((_ x) #'(do-something-with x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`raise-syntax-error`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/exns.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._raise-syntax-error%29%29) directly.

Internally, `syntax-violation` is [implemented in Racket](https://github.com/racket/r6rs/blob/master/r6rs-lib/rnrs/syntax-case-6.rkt#L28) by using `raise-syntax-error`.